# How to notify when last web service call completed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, axios

I would like to call this chunk of code:

```
this.setState({ // <------------ CODE 1
  pages: pages
});
```

only when all `axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/' + page.id + '/events?access_token=' + accessToken)` has completed. `CODE 2`

How to implement it in Javascript?

```
let accessToken = response.accessToken
axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me/accounts?fields=id,name&access_token=' + response.accessToken)
.then(response => {
console.log("test")
let pageList = response.data.data.map(page => {
  console.log("page " + page.id + " " + page.name);
  this.setState({
    page: response.data.data
  });

  var pages = {}; // <------------ CODE 2
  axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/' + page.id + '/events?access_token=' + accessToken)
  .then(response => {
    console.log("test 2");
    var events = {};
    let eventList = response.data.data.map(event => {
      console.log("event " + event.id + " " + event.name);
      events[event.id] = event.name;
    });
    pages[page.id] = [page.name, events];
  })

  this.setState({ // <------------ CODE 1
    pages: pages
  });
})
})
```

Comment: Do you wish to wait for all of them no matter if they rejected or resolved, or do you want it to set state at the first Reject ?

Comment: Hi, no matter if they rejected.

Comment: Have a look at [axios.all](https://github.com/axios/axios#user-content-axiosalliterable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to wait for every [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to complete before setting state, we could utilize [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). However, Promise.all will cancel all requests if one promise rejects. That's why we are adding `.catch(e => e)`, which all it really does is catch any reject and pass it to Promise.all regularly, like the promise resolved.

Combined with `await` we can wait for Promise.all, then loop over the results, call `setState` or whatever you'd really like.

```
let accessToken = response.accessToken;
axios
  .get(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me/accounts?fields=id,name&access_token=" +
      response.accessToken
  )
  .then(async pagesResponse => {
    console.log("test");
    let promisesArray = pagesResponse.data.data.map(async page => {
      console.log("page " + page.id + " " + page.name);
      this.setState({
        page: response.data.data
      });

      return axios
        .get(
          "https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/" +
            page.id +
            "/events?access_token=" +
            accessToken
        )
        .catch(e => e);
    });

    const responses = await Promise.all(promisesArray);
    var pages = {}; // <------------ CODE 2
    responses.forEach((response, i) => {
      console.log("test 2");
      var events = {};
      let eventList = response.data.data.map(event => {
        console.log("event " + event.id + " " + event.name);
        events[event.id] = event.name;
      });
      const page = pagesResponse.data.data[i];
      pages[page.id] = [page.name, events];
    });

    this.setState({
      // <------------ CODE 1
      pages: pages
    });
  });
```

Hope it's clear! Let me know if you need any further explanation.

Comment: I added the async, it was missing in the callback of the first get

Comment: My problem that `page.id` and `page.name` is not available here: `pages[page.id] = [page.name, events];`

Comment: Try now. I used the responses loop indices in order to access the relevant page. Let me know how it goes.